# Python, crear dos listas dentro de una clase

Tags: python

Necesito definir dos listas dependiendo de si el cliente es o no frecuente. Se que debo de utilizar un If and Elif, pero no estoy seguro de como exactamente ni si debo de hacerlo dentro de **init** o de mi metodo para agregar informacion. Aqui el codigo:

```
class Cola:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cola = []        
#metodo para agregar elementos en la estructura tipo cola
    def agregar(self, elemento):
        self.cola.append(elemento)

def ingreso():
    frecuente = input("  ¿Es cliente frecuente? (s/n):  ")
    if frecuente == "s" or "S" or "SI" or "si":
        tipo = "Cliente frecuente"
    else:
        tipo = "Otro tipo"
    nombre = input("  Nombre de cliente:  ")
    apellido = (input("  Apellido:  "))
    return [nombre, apellido, tipo]

cola_item = Cola()
cola_item.agregar(ingreso())
```

Cualquier comentario, quedo atento.

Gracias.

Comment: No termina de quedarme claro lo que deseas exactamente, ¿la idea sería tener una sola cola y ordenar cada cliente en ella según membresía y luego por orden de ingreso? ¿O tener dos colas, una para los miembros y otra para los no miembros? ¿O nada de eso y estoy perdido completamente :)?

Comment: La idea es tener dos colas, una para cada tipo de cliente. Aunque la primera idea suena mucho a lo que finalmente quiero hacer. Básicamente es Primeras Entradas Primeras Salidas, dando prioridad a clientes con membresía.

Comment: a ver si entendí, lo que quieres es crear dos colas (osea dos listas) , uno para clientes con vip y otra para clientes normales luego preguntar el nombre apellido y si es vip o no y si llega a ser vip agregarlo a la lista vip y si es normal agregarlo a la lista normal?

Comment: Si. Esto con el objetivo de resolver lo siguiente: llegan al establecimiento diversos clientes, siempre se va a atender a los que sean frecuentes antes que a los demás. Mi idea es tener dos colas y dependiendo de si len>0 atender a frecuentes, de otra forma, atender al resto. Aunque FJSevilla ya planteo crear una sola cola y ordenar según su membresía y arribo.

Comment: Acabo de notar que tenía Membresía y eso confundida, ya lo edite.

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí muy bien la idea, pero creo que te refieres a algo como esto.

Lo que hice fue ponerlo en bucle y crear dos listas la colaVip y la colaNormal hacer las mismas preguntas y almacenarlo en la lista vip si es tipo vip o en la lista normal si es tipo normal, luego cree 2 metodos para consultar las respectivas listas.

Cualquier duda me preguntas.

```
class Cola:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cola = []
        self.colaVip = []
        self.colaNormal = []
#metodo para agregar elementos en la estructura tipo cola
    def agregar(self, elemento):
        self.cola.append(elemento)

    def ingreso(self):
        while True:
            frecuente = input("  ¿Es cliente frecuente? (s/n):  ")
            if frecuente == "s" or frecuente == "S" or frecuente == "SI" or frecuente == "si":
                tipo = "Cliente frecuente"

            elif frecuente == "n" or frecuente == "N" or frecuente == "NO" or frecuente == "no":
                tipo = "Otro tipo"

            else:
                print("[Error] Ingrese si o no.")
                continue

            nombre = input("  Nombre de cliente:  ")
            apellido = (input("  Apellido:  "))

            if tipo == "Cliente frecuente":
                self.colaVip.append(nombre)
                self.colaVip.append(apellido)
                self.colaVip.append(tipo)

                self.consultarlistaVip()

                print("======================")
                preguntar = input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente?: ")
                if preguntar == "s" or preguntar == "S" or preguntar == "SI" or preguntar == "si":
                    continue
                elif preguntar == "n" or preguntar == "N" or preguntar == "NO" or preguntar == "no":
                    break

            elif tipo == "Otro tipo":
                self.colaNormal.append(nombre)
                self.colaNormal.append(apellido)
                self.colaNormal.append(tipo)

                self.consultarlistaNormal()

                print("======================")
                preguntar = input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente?: ")
                if preguntar == "s" or preguntar == "S" or preguntar == "SI" or preguntar == "si":
                    continue
                elif preguntar == "n" or preguntar == "N" or preguntar == "NO" or preguntar == "no":
                    break

    def consultarlistaNormal(self):
        return print(self.colaNormal)

    def consultarlistaVip(self):
        return print(self.colaVip)

Cola().ingreso()
```

Answer (score 0):

No existe una única forma de estructurar la implementación, pero a grandes rasgos:

- **Dos colas, una para miembros y otra para no miembros**

  En este la separación obviamente debes hacerla fuera de la clase que implementa la cola, por ejemplo:

  ```
  def datos_cliente():
      frecuente = input("  ¿Es cliente frecuente? (s/n):  ").lower()
      tipo = "miembro" if frecuente == "s" or frecuente == "si" else "nuevo"
      nombre = input("  Nombre de cliente:  ")
      apellido = (input("  Apellido:  "))
      return [nombre, apellido, tipo]

  def ingreso(cola_miembros, cola_no_miembros):
      cliente = datos_cliente()
      if cliente[2] == "miembro":
          cola_miembros.agregar(cliente)
      else:
          cola_no_miembros.agregar(cliente)


  miembros = Cola()
  no_miembros = Cola()
  ingreso(miembros, no_miembros)
  ```
- **Una cola para todos los clientes con prioridad para miembros (PriorityQueue)**:

  En este caso es la clase `Cola` debe establecer la lógica para poner primero a los clientes miembro por orden de ingreso y a continuación los no miembros también por orden de ingreso.

  Tienes varias formas de implementar la cola con prioridad, por ejemplo:

  ```
  class Cola:
      def __init__(self):
          self._cola = []

      def agregar(self, new_item, prioridad: int):
          for index, item in enumerate(self._cola):
              if prioridad < item[0]:
                  self._cola.insert(index, (prioridad, new_item))
                  break # No olvidarse de romper el ciclo o se lia parda :)
          else: # Se ha recorrido toda la lista sin insertar
              self._cola.append((prioridad, new_item))

      def obtener(self):
          if self._cola:
              return self._cola.pop(0)[1]


      def __str__(self):
          return " <<<<< ".join(str(item) for _, item in self._cola)
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> cola = Cola()
  > >>> cola.agregar(["Manuel", "García", "Miembro"], 1)
  > >>> cola.agregar(["Rafael", "Muñoz", "Nuevo"], 2)
  > >>> cola.agregar(["Laura", "Ruiz", "Nuevo"], 2)
  > >>> cola.agregar(["Luis", "Aguilera", "Miembro"], 1)
  > >>> cola.agregar(["María", "Lopez", "Miembro"], 1)
  > >>> print(cola)
  > ['José', 'Ruiz', 'Nuevo'] <<<<< ['Manuel', 'García', 'Miembro'] <<<<< ['Luis', 'Aguilera', 'Miembro'] <<<<< ['María', 'Lopez', 'Miembro'] <<<<< ['Rafael', 'Muñoz', 'Nuevo'] <<<<< ['Laura', 'Ruiz', 'Nuevo']
  > ```

  Obviamente podrías implementar dentro de la clase el establecimiento de la prioridad en base al tipo de cliente, pero esto hace tu clase menos genérica:

  ```
  class Cola:
      def __init__(self):
          self._cola = []

      def agregar(self, new_item):
          if new_item[2] == "Miembro":
              prioridad = 1
          else:
              prioridad = 2

          for index, item in enumerate(self._cola):
              if prioridad < item[0]:
                  self._cola.insert(index, (prioridad, new_item))
                  break # No olvidarse de romper el ciclo o se lia parda :)
          else: # Se ha recorrido toda la lista sin insertar
              self._cola.append((prioridad, new_item))

      def obtener(self):
          if self._cola:
              return self._cola.pop(0)[1]


      def __str__(self):
          return " <<<<< ".join(str(item) for _, item in self._cola)


  cola = Cola()
  cola.agregar(["Manuel", "García", "Miembro"])
  cola.agregar(["Rafael", "Muñoz", "Nuevo"])
  cola.agregar(["Laura", "Ruiz", "Nuevo"])
  cola.agregar(["Luis", "Aguilera", "Miembro"])
  cola.agregar(["María", "Lopez", "Miembro"])
  ```

---

Me he limitado a usar una lista para implementar la cola tal como se plantea en el ejemplo de la pregunta, no es el método más eficiente necesariamente.

Nótese que Python implementa en el módulo [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) de la biblioteca estándar una cola (`queue.Queue`) y una cola con prioridad (`queue.PriorityQueue`):

```
import dataclasses
import queue


@dataclasses.dataclass(order=True)
class Cliente:
    nombre: str = dataclasses.field(compare=False)
    apellidos: str = dataclasses.field(compare=False)
    tipo: str = dataclasses.field(compare=False)
    _prioridad: int =  dataclasses.field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self. _prioridad: int = 2
        if self.tipo == "Miembro":
            self._prioridad = 1
        else:
            self._prioridad = 2


cola = queue.PriorityQueue()
cola.put(Cliente("Manuel", "García", "Miembro"))
cola.put(Cliente("Rafael", "Muñoz", "Nuevo"))
cola.put(Cliente("Laura", "Ruiz", "Nuevo"))
cola.put(Cliente("Luis", "Aguilera", "Miembro"))
cola.put(Cliente("María", "Lopez", "Miembro"))

while True:
    try:
        cliente = cola.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        break
    else:
        print(cliente)
```

> ```
> Cliente(nombre='Manuel', apellidos='García', tipo='Miembro')
> Cliente(nombre='Luis', apellidos='Aguilera', tipo='Miembro')
> Cliente(nombre='María', apellidos='Lopez', tipo='Miembro')
> Cliente(nombre='Rafael', apellidos='Muñoz', tipo='Nuevo')
> Cliente(nombre='Laura', apellidos='Ruiz', tipo='Nuevo')
> ```